# Unity Sprite Gallery

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a code that can access a folder, and convert all the jpg files to sprites in unity, can someone help me.

```cs
public class Gallery : MonoBehaviour {
 
     public Sprite[] gallery;
     public Image displayImage;
     public Button nextImg;
     public Button prevImg;
     public int i = 0;

     void Start ()
     {
        string[] Images = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Bandeira/Downloads/Menu Start/Assets/Sprite/","*.jpg");

        foreach (var image in Images)
        {   
            Debug.Log(image);
            gallery[i] = Resources.Load(image) as Sprite;
            i++;
        }
     }

     void Update () 
     {
        displayImage.sprite = gallery[i];
     }

     public void BtnNext (){
         if(i + 1 < gallery.Length){
             i++;
         }
     }
 
     public void BtnPrev () {
         if (i - 1 >= 0){
             i--;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the site guidelines on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What have you actually tried that's going wrong?

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Resources.Load which is only work if the item is in the Resources folder of the project. If you want to load external file you need to load it with UnityWebRequest Class. Here I post the code to load images from it's path.

```
public class Gallery : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Sprite> gallery = new List<Sprite>();
    public Image displayImage;
    public Button nextImg;
    public Button prevImg;
    public int i = 0;

    void Start ()
    {
        var Images = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Bandeira/Downloads/Menu Start/Assets/Sprite/","*.jpg");

        StartCoroutine(LoadImages(Images));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadImages(string[] Images)
    {
        foreach (var path in Images)
        {
            using (var uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file:///" + path))
            {
                yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            
                if (uwr.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                {
                    Debug.Log(uwr.error);
                    yield break;
                }
            
                var tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
                    
                var sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0f, 0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 50f, 0, SpriteMeshType.FullRect);
                gallery.Add(sprite);
                uwr.Dispose();
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public void BtnNext (){
        if(i + 1 < gallery.Count){
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        displayImage.sprite = gallery[i];
    }
 
    public void BtnPrev () {
        if (i - 1 >= 0){
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            i = gallery.Count;
        }
        displayImage.sprite = gallery[i];
    }
}
```

now you will need to wait until it is done loading images and good to go.

Comment: Ty for the comment, but the code still gives-me a error, "Assets\Scripts\Gallery.cs(8,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;  add this in the imports.